# Visual Studio 2015 TypeScript Files Disappear in Chrome

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.8

I am working in Visual Studio 2015 using Angular 2 and TypeScript 1.8 and every once in a while, Chrome will throw a whole bunch of errors and I notice, while looking at the Sources, my .js files are all there but the .ts files are not.

I have to restart VS a couple times and get it to retranspile a couple .ts files in order for them all to show up again in the Chrome debugger.

It is very strange.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out but wanted to post my fix, just in case anyone else comes across it and finds it useful.

The problem I was having was actually related to my TypeScript compiler not generating the .js.map files for my .ts files when transpiling them.

Once my TypeScript Compiler was fixed, I saved my .ts files, the .js.map files were generated and the files reappeared in Chrome